# Display Issue with Multiple Monitors JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml, multiple-monitors

My application functions as intended, but there are display issues when you run it. When it runs, the java window pops up with the correct window size, but the controls within the window are huge for some reason. The only way I've been able to work around this and get them to display at their normal size is if I drag the window over to one of my other monitors, drop it (at which point the oversized controls shift around a bit), and then drag it back to the laptop monitor. Then the controls shrink back and display properly.

If I drag it back over to one of my other monitors, however, the controls blow up again.

I'm using IntelliJ 14 and Scene Builder 2.0 running on MacOSX 10.10.3.

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="332.0" prefWidth="404.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="408.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="408.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Button id="btnTest" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#foo" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="275.0" text="Generate Encryption Key" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <Label fx:id="lblTop" alignment="TOP_CENTER" contentDisplay="TOP" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets top="35.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="txtKey" alignment="CENTER" editable="false" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Controller:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.beans.EventHandler;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;



public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TextField txtKey;
    @FXML
    private Label lblTop;
    @FXML
    private Button btnButton;

    Random rnd = new Random();
    private char[] pool = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources){
        assert btnButton != null : "fx:id=\"txtKey\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'sample.fxml'.";
    }


        public void foo (ActionEvent actionEvent){
            String key = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
                key = key + pool[rnd.nextInt(36)];
            }

            lblTop.setText("Your Encryption Key is:");
            txtKey.setText(key);
    }

}
```

Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Encryption Key Generator");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

UPADATE:

This problem seems to be an IntelliJ issue. I decided to try to build my application and after I ran the JAR, it worked perfectly. The application's logic functioned and the aforementioned display problems weren't occurring anymore.

It does do a little resizing jitter when moving between monitors, but it never displays the elements incorrectly.